# group list by first four letters of a field and set the value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a custom type OrderStatus.

```
class OrderStatus
{
    string prodCode
    bool Issue
}
```

I have list of OrderStatus called OrderList, example below

```
prodCode    issue
BTCR        false
BTCRRED     false
BTCROUT     true
BTCM        false
BTCMOUT     false
```

I want to group the prodCode on the first four letter, so the list above would just have BTCR & BTCM in it. So something like below

```
prodCode    Issue
BTCR        true
BTCM        false
```

Please note BTCR issue is now true so if any three of the product codes that start with BTCR have an issue this need to be shown.

How do I go about this? Take it this is a linq problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result=list.GroupBy(o=>o.prodCode.Substring(0,4))
  .Select(o=>new OrderStatus {prodCode=o.Key,Issue=o.Any(o2=>o2.Issue)});
```

Here's the test: http://ideone.com/20Olpz

Comment: He's worried about BTCR repeats